# I want to send form and some text to another file with ajax or json or whatever. Currently it is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

So I have an onclick function which sends a message to another php file which sends the message to the database. I want to send to the php file, the whole form and a specific chat_index value. So far I have:

```
$(".comin").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var item_id = this.id;
    alert(item_id);

    if($.get('sendcom.php?q=' + item_id, $('#comform').serialize())) {
      var a = $(".comin").val();
      alert(a);
      document.getElementById(item_id).value = "";
      //sent and cleared
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Try this syntax. This should work for you. `$.ajax({
        url: '/new-user.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });`

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: yes yes yes no yes

Comment: check my answer

Comment: There are probably like 8000 ajax post examples on SO. I don't think there is a need for another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post your data in json format,

```
$(".comin").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
        var chatData = {
            q: item_id,
            formData:$('#comform').serialize()
        }
         $.ajax({
            url: 'sendcom.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: chatData,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#target').html(data.msg);
            }

        });
    }
});
```